# c++ builder. Variables static en class

Tags: c++

llevo poco con builder e intento realizar un ejercicio en el que se almacenan valores de la posición y tamaño del form en variables estáticas, me baso en Borland C++builder 6 developer´s guide páginas 86 y 87. Para ello pretendía crear una clase en un archivo .h

```
class VGlobales {

    // atributos
    private: static int posicionAlto;
    private: static int posicionAncho;
    private: static int posicionArriba;
    private: static int posicionIzquierda;

    // constructor privado
    private: VGlobales();

    // métodos setting
    public: static void setposicionAlto(
        int nuevaposicionAlto) {posicionAlto = nuevaposicionAlto;}
    public: static void setposicionAncho(
        int nuevaposicionAncho) {posicionAncho = nuevaposicionAncho;}
    public: static void setposicionArriba(
        int nuevaposicionArriba) {posicionArriba = nuevaposicionArriba;}
    public: static void setposicionIzquierda(
        int nuevaposicionIzquierda) {posicionIzquierda =     nuevaposicionIzquierda;}

    // métodos getting
    public: static int getposicionAlto() {return posicionAlto;}
    public: static int getposicionAncho() {return posicionAncho;}
    public: static int getposicionArriba() {return posicionArriba;}
    public: static int getposicionIzquierda() {return posicionIzquierda;}
};
```

y posteriomente en cada form antes de cerrar almacenar estos valores

```
VGlobales::setposicionAlto(Form1->Width);
VGlobales::setposicionAncho(Form1->Height);
VGlobales::setposicionArriba(Form1->Top);
VGlobales::setposicionIzquierda(Form1->Left);
```

Perdón si está un poco liado pero lo he modificado muchas veces, no encuentro la forma adecuada de incluir las variables nuevaposicion llamando a los métodos.

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. ¿Qué problema estás teniendo? (Por cierto, al contrario que en C#, en C++ no es necesario repetir tantas veces `public` y `private`).

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. ¿Cual es tu pregunta exactamente? Te recomiendo visititar el [tour] de bienvenida para que te puedas hacer una idea acerca del funcionamiento de este portal.

Comment: Pregunto por la forma adecuada de llamar a los métodos pasando los valores actuales del form. Entiendo que lo que es la clase debería estar bien, aunque no estoy seguro, hace mucho que no veo nada de C y soy nuevo con c++ builder. Gracias.

Comment: Te recomiendo editar la pregunta para añadir justamente "_la pregunta que te falta_" y que has añadido como comentario

Comment: Ayudaría mucho a resolver tu problema sin nos indicaras **el error exacto** que obtienes; evitaríamos el dar *palos de ciego* :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La definición de variables estáticas consta de **2** partes:

1. Declaración.
2. Instanciación.

En tu código, haces la 1ª parte. **Declaras** la variable.

Te faltaría la segunda: **Instanciarla**.

Para ello, crea un archivo aparte, `archivo.cpp`, que contenga lo siguiente:

```
int VGlobales::posicionAlto;
int VGlobales::posicionAncho;
int VGlobales::posicionArriba;
int VGlobales::posicionIzquierda;
```

Con eso debería de ser suficiente.

Comment: Puede ser esa la cuestión, pretendía generar una serie de archivos .h con las clases, entonces ¿en builder es mejor añadir unit que contienen los .h y los .cpp? ¿no hay mejor forma si debes añadir muchas clases?

Comment: Depende de lo que quieras hacer. En C++, generalmente se usan los `.h`  o `.hpp` para las declaraciones (clases, funciones, ...), mientras que **el cuerpo** de dichas funciones se implementa en archivos `.cpp`. Depende de si usas plantillas, si las funciones son `inline` (como las que muestras tú), la versión del C++ subyacente (no se que compilador usa Builder) ...